# Window closing not working because of a race condition

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, race-condition

Here's my code:

```
private void OpenLoadingWindow()
{
    loadingWindow = new LoadingView();
    loadingWindow.Closed += new EventHandler(LoadingWindow_Closed);

    _go = true;
    loadingWindow.ShowDialog();
}

public void OpenLoadingWindowInNewThread()
{
    thread = new Thread(x => OpenLoadingWindow());
    thread.IsBackground = true;
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();

    lock (_locker)                 
    {                              
        Monitor.Pulse(_locker);
    }
}

public void CloseLoadingWindow()
{
    lock (_locker)
        while (!_go)
            Monitor.Wait (_locker);

    if (loadingWindow != null)
    {
        loadingWindow.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() =>
        {
            _go = false;
            loadingWindow.Close();
            loadingWindow = null;
        }));
    }
}
```

In code I first call OpenLoadingWindowInNewThread() and after that I call CloseLoadingWindow(). However, the first time the code is executed it works fine. But after that, the code in CloseLoadingWindow(), in BeginInvoke doesnt get executed. What am I doing wrong?

What I want to achieve is this: open the loading window, execute some code. After the code is execited I call the closing method, I want to close the loading window.

Comment: Are you opening a separate window each time?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov No, it's the same window.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve? It you can explain that, you may get better answers.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel What I want to achieve is this: open the loading window, execute some code. After the code is execited I call the closing method, I want to close the loading window.

Comment: It should not have worked at all. That first time success was probably just luck. The (entire) GUI is not thread-safe, you can't do this. And you don't have to, the Thread is not needed..

Comment: @HenkHolterman But if I dont use threads I get error at this line: loadingWindow = new LoadingView();, saying that the calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.

Comment: The calling thread should be the Main thread, and that should indeed be STA.

Comment: It's not clear what you are doing. There should be 2 critical sections: one to create window, set `_go` and `ShowDialog` and another to close window and reset `_go`. I can't understand pulsing in `OpenLoadingWindowInNewThread`, why? Maybe you just need *modeless* window (opened by using `Show()`, not `ShowDialog()`)?

Answer (score 2):

The main problem here is that you are creating a second thread for UI. Don't do that.

Unfortunately, you didn't provide a good code example. So for the sake of an answer, let's assume you're doing something like this:

```
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoLoadingWork();
}

void DoLoadingWork()
{
    OpenLoadingWindowInNewThread();
    LoadingWork();
    CloseLoadingWindow();
}
```

I.e. some event happened in your UI, and now you have to do some work. You implemented this by calling the methods you've shown in your question, processing the work in your UI thread and creating a second thread to show the dialog.

This is the wrong way to approach this. Instead, you should keep all of your UI in the same thread, and do the work in a different thread. That would look more like this:

```
void DoLoadingWork()
{
    using (LoadingView form = new LoadingView())
    {
        form.Shown += async (sender, e) =>
        {
            await Task.Run(() => LoadingWork());
            form.Close();
        };

        form.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

This version does the following:

1. Creates your status dialog in the UI thread
2. Subscribes to the `Shown` event, to ensure the dialog is visible before anything else happens
3. Shows the dialog
4. Once the dialog is shown, a new thread is started to execute the `LoadingWork()` method
5. When the `LoadingWork()` method completes, the dialog is closed, allowing the dialog to be disposed and the `DoLoadingWork()` method to return.

Note that even if you have to interact with the UI from the code that does the processing, or if you need a way to interrupt the processing, the above is still the correct way to do things. Those other aspects of the requirements can easily be implemented, using standard idioms for dealing with them.

Without an actual example of what that processing might be, and how the UI interaction and/or interruption works, it's impossible to say exactly how that part would be implemented. But it would generally involve using `Invoke()` for UI interaction (or even better, refactoring the processing so that it uses `async`/`await`, with UI interaction occurring between `await` statements for the individual pieces of the work) and a flag or `CancellationToken` to deal with interrupting the thread.

If your processing does in fact interact with the UI, and you did in fact run it in the UI thread, then it's likely you've got calls to methods like `Refresh()` or `Application.DoEvents()` interspersed. These methods are practically never required, and IMHO are always a sign that the code has been implemented incorrectly. As an added benefit of changing your implementation to put the right code in the right thread, you won't have to use any of those methods to interact with the UI (instead, you'll use `Invoke()`).